# precision_recall_fscore_support support returns None

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to extract all the relevant 'weighted average' measures from classification report.
I get the recall, precision and fscore correct. support, however returns None, whereas I expect it to be, 500 which is the total of 'yes' in my multiclass classification.

I run the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
precision,recall,fscore,support=score(y_test, y_pred,average='weighted')
print('precision:', precision)
print('recall:', recall)
print('fscore:', fscore)
print('support:', support)
```

> precision: 0.43
> recall: 0.54
> fscore: 0.50
> support: None

Here's how the weighted row looks like when I run the classification report instead:

```
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, digits=2))
```

> weighted avg       0.43      0.54      0.50       500

I found the following in documentation:

> Returns
> supportNone (if average is not None) or array of int, shape =[n_unique_labels]

How can I extract the correct support?

Comment: Don't know what could be the reasoning behind the different approach, but in `precision_recall_fscore_support` they are simply returning `support=None` whenever metrics are averaged ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L1635)); on the other hand, `classification_report` calls `precision_recall_fscore_support`, but `support` is retrieved as the sum of per-class supports when averaging is considered rather than left equal to None. Couldn't you just retrieve it as the dimension of your label?

Comment: Within `classification_report`: results without averaging are computed first via `precision_recall_fscore_support`, per-class `supports` included ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L2157)); then if some form of averaging is considered the previous method is called and returns no support, which is obtained instead as the sum of the ones computed before ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L2204))

Comment: I could, but my question was whether it's possible via precision_recall_fscore_support

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `multilabel_confusion_matrix`  (sklearn function) and sum all true labels. Like the documentation said you wont get the support if you have `average` other than `None`.

```
MCM = multilabel_confusion_matrix(
        y_true,
        y_pred,
        labels=labels,
    )
    tp_sum = MCM[:, 1, 1]
    Support = tp_sum + MCM[:, 1, 0]
```